# I get Error Expression is not assignable for

Tags: c

Can you tell me why "p" is not assignable?

---

```
void gl_mean (double x,double *count, double *mean) {
  double p;
  x+(*mean**count) / *count+1=p;
  printf("%f",p);
}
```

**Picture of Clion Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: You aren't assigning p, you're assigning `x+(*mean**count) / *count+1`

Comment: oh well thank you :D didnt think the order mattered

Comment: If the importance of order is not already clear to you, then you might want to follow a few tutorials. They will provide you with many examples and thereby with some experience.

Answer (score 3):

[.sdrawkcab](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backwards) si edoC

```
void gl_mean (double x,double *count, double *mean) {
  double p;
  // x+(*mean**count) / *count+1=p;
  p = x+(*mean * *count) / *count + 1;
  printf("%f",p);
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is of course funny. But maybe also giving one more targeted at beginners would be an improvement of the usefulness, as seen from point of view of a beginner.

Comment: @Yunnosch Perhaps, yet then I would be duplicating your good answer.  OP's are fickle: sometimes a terse answer is best - sometimes a well explained one works better.  IAC, OP has a variety here to use.

Comment: :-) I like the idea that our two answers together are best value for SO. Thanks for the compliment and I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Not `p` is the problem.
It cannot be asssigned because that which you try to assign it to is an expression, which is an "rvalue", i.e. something which can only be on the right side of an assignment.

The problem should become clear if you try to explain this line

```
x+(*mean**count) / *count+1=p;
```

Try to identify the variable you are trying to assign to.

In order to assign something you need to assign an rvalue, probably your expression, to an lvalue, which most likely is `p`.

The code for what you probably intended is therefor most likely

```
p=...;
```

I am not sure that your expression is perfectly clear, so I will leave it at this.